# ul li limit results and show more on hover

Tags: php, jquery, css, html-lists

I have a `ul` generated by a PHP function.

```
<ul> 
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
</li>
```

I want to "limit" results and show list in this way (in HTML pages)

```
Item1 - Item2 - 3 more...
```

The "3 more" must be shown after mouse hover.

Is that possible?  How can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: Try Googling for a jQuery pagination plugin.

Comment: It's a good question but even if you're a beginner with something, you have to try by yourself. It's a very good way to begin before asking here.

Answer (score 2):

At first, you can have this CSS in place

```
ul li:nth-child(-n+5) {display:none}  /* Shows only first 5*/
.showAll {display:block;}
```

Then on hover you can do..

```
$('ul')
.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find('li').filter(':not(:visible)').addClass('showAll'); 
    //shows hidden li's
})
.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find('li.showAll').removeClass('showAll');
    //hides those li's
});
```

Comment: Sorry, clicked "post" by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

First of all we need to state our limit and *more* counter:

```
var limit = 3
var more = 0
```

Then we can hide all `li`s that exceed our limit:

```
$("#tricky_list li").each(function(index) {
    if(index >= limit){
        $(this).hide();
        more++;
    }
});
```

If there were any `li` tags hidden place info:

```
if(more){
    $("#tricky_list").append('<li class="more">' + more + ' more</li>');
}
```

Let's make it a trigger and order to show hidden `li`s on `mouseover`.

```
$("#tricky_list li.more").live("mouseover", function(){
    $("#tricky_list li").each(function(index) {
            $(this).show();
    });
    $("#tricky_list li.more").hide()
});
```

​This way you have clean html&css and everything is done seamlessly by js.

http://jsfiddle.net/27bvG/

Answer (score 1):

```
var numToShow = 3;
var moreLi;
$('ul').children('li').hide().each(function() {
    if ($(this).index() < numToShow) {
        $(this).show();
    }
}).parent('ul').append('<li><a href="#" id="showMore">More</a></li>');

$('#showMore').click(function() {
    moreLi = $(this).parent('li');
    moreLi.siblings().show();
    moreLi.remove();
});
```

There's probably a much more efficient way to write it and it could certainly be more robust, but this is a quick way to what you're looking for.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ak2X/

Answer (score 0):

This should help get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/qnQ7r/